# Objective c: How to know the progress of unzipping in using ZipArchive

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, php-ziparchive

I use ZipArchive to unzip my file in objective c. Is there a way of knowing the progress when it starts to unzip (like the percentage done etc.). Or I have to create a delegate to retrieve the progress by myself? Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way of doing that with ZipArchive. [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) has this feature implemented on a delegate method:

```
- (void)zipArchiveDidUnzipFileAtIndex:(NSInteger)fileIndex totalFiles:(NSInteger)totalFiles archivePath:(NSString *)archivePath fileInfo:(unz_file_info)fileInfo;
```